# JQuery focus without entering key event shortcut

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using [keymaster](https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster) library for defining and dispatching keyboard shortcuts, I defined shortcut key `/` to focus input element.

```
key('/', function() {
    $(".topbar input").focus();
  });
```

The issue is that when the `/` key is pressed, the input is focused with `/` entered value. I want to get rid of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
key('/', function(event) {
   $(".topbar input").focus();
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You have to define event first ;)

Answer (score 0):

It gets focused because you tell it to do so.

Remove this line:

```
 $(".topbar input").focus();
```

Or give it a function so that you can do stuff when it gets focused

```
$(".topbar input").focus(function(){

});
```